# Latch Circuit: Beginner

Tags: led, latch

I am trying to implement a simple latching circuit that will turn an LED on if the signal from an AND gate is high (LED latches ON if high, and only way to reset is to remove power). I was thinking of using an SR latch, where I reset to the initial state (resulting in an off LED) then when the signal comes in, I switch the state. However, I don't know if 1) this is the right way to do this (seems a bit too complicated, since I don't need 2 outputs or 2 inputs) or 2) how exactly this would even be implemented in a circuit (especially the initial reset, or the power removal feature).

I hope my question is clear, since I am a beginner and am not sure if my descriptions are technically informative. I appreciate any help!

EDIT1: Attempt 1 Using SCR and Transistor:

[image]

Comment: Do you require it to be digital logic?  You can also do this with an SCR or TRIAC.

Comment: Yes, the logic comes from 2 comparator inputs. I pass through an AND gate and if both are high, a timer cirucit is triggered. If these timer reaches a given time, then the circuit should latch

Comment: So it sounds like it is the output of the **timers** that you need to latch, not the input to the timers?

Comment: Yes, that;s correct

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to complicate it with digital logic, just use an SCR.

When power is first applied no current flows through the LED.
After the button has been pressed, then the SCR is latched on and the LED is lit.
The only way to turn it off is to stop current from flowing through the SCR ie. remove power.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUW7oi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

EDIT with AND gate control

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD6wFQ.png)</sup>

Comment: The AND gate uses 2 comparator input, so if both the comparator inputs are high, then the LED turns on. So I think I would have to replace the switch with something.

Comment: Should I use a transistor here?

Comment: @EENoob see the update with an AND gate to control it.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, if the voltage from AND1 is high, then SCR1 latches ON?

Comment: You might find purchasing a small SCR isn't as easy as you think.  Here a link on how to make your own. _Can a thyristor be built from two transistors?_ https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/344321/can-a-thyristor-be-built-from-two-transistors

Comment: @EENoob yes that is correct.

Comment: @DDuck 851 active and in stock: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/thyristors-scrs/281?s=N4IgjCBcpgnAHLKoDGUBmBDANgZwKYA0IA9lANogAMIAusQA4AuUIAykwE4CWAdgOYgAvsQC0AJmQg0kLgFcipCiACsdRi0ghhIkJMiVcKTnSFA